# Truecaller like alert dialog in dart

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a true caller like alert dialog in flutter. Since I am very new to flutter+dart, I was looking for any out of the box implementation. So far I have found [system_alert_window](https://pub.dev/packages/system_alert_window) but this creates the alert dialogue in JAVA and uses **platform channels** to communicate with it. My question is that if it's possible to do this is pure flutter+dart.

I do not know if this kind of dialogues has any special names, also in truecaller the dialogue is shown regardless the app is running or not. Can anyone provide some pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do with flutter

You can only go with Java.

> Flollow the steps

your project > android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

add this permission on your Androidmanifest.xml file

after adding the permission add the below receiver class

```
 <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

the receiver class

**ServiceReceiver.Java**

```
    public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                    System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
 WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null); // Code for inflating xml layout
                int LAYOUT_FLAG;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
                } else {
                    LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
                }
                WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LAYOUT_FLAG,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
  windowManager.addView(view, params);
                }
            },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
```

add the below xml file on the folder

your project > android > app > src > main > res > layout > popup_window.xml

**popup_window.xml**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_color"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/paymentlogo"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/rsoft_logo"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/rsoft_logo" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Anand"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_close"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.7"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_record_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/btw_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#bab9b9" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/details_adp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_icon"
                                android:layout_width="17dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                android:layout_height="17dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_incoming"

                                android:textSize="10sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_mobile"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="7667673691"
                                android:padding="0dp"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_mobile_"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="Incomingg"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                       <!-- <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:padding="3dp">
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_im"
                                android:layout_width="14dp"
                                android:layout_height="14dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/sim" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_sim"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                                android:text="Incomingg"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>-->

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_lead"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:text="Save As Lead"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_btn"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

       




        </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_overlay_window](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window). Its JAVA only but works fine. The example app has a truecaller like overlay demo. The other answer is correct, no it can't be done in pure flutter.